# mod_rewrite last match

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess is located in `localhost/me/.htaccess`, and I want to append anything after the last / with .php

e.g. `localhost/me/test/index` rewrites to `localhost/me/test/index.php`

So far `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` works for `localhost/me/index`, but I can't get it working for the first example up there. Why doesn't `^/([A-Za-z]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]` work, and how do I change it to work?

Comment: Haven't played with rewrite in a while..but the `^` could be forcing it to match all the way from the start of the path which might contain multiple slashes(?) In that case you'll never get a match. So I would just try and ditch the `^` and see what happens. The `$` already hooks it onto the end, and the pattern should be greedy..so it'll eat up everything after a slash all the way to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're matching only on alpha letters and you don't have a `/` in the character class, but your URI is `me/test/index` .  Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z/]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also, since you're using `[NC]`, you really only need `a-z` rather than `A-Za-z` but it doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use this rule:

```
# add .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

1. It will check if such .php exist before rewriting
2. The main problem you had is your pattern: `^([A-Za-z]+)$` it will match `index` but not `test/index` as it only allows `a-z` characters. You would need to add `/` into a pattern:  `^([a-z/]+)$`.
3. because you have `[NC]` flag (no case matching), there is no need to have both `A-Z` and `a-z`
4. I'm using more global/general pattern `(.+)`-- it will match any characters and because it comes with "check if file exist" conditions, there is no need to worry about limited set of characters.

Comment: Although this answer is more extensive, it forces me to add in RewriteCond due to the `(.+)` modifier matching extensions. Michael's answer is simpler. It lets the .php extension go through because it won't match the regex, and it doesn't interfere with my other files, like my stylesheets. I did upvote for noticing the [NC] flag though!